# Usage of `hash` method

Tags: python, hash

How do you use the `hash` method?

```
>>> def foo():
>>>    return 'foo'
>>> f = foo()
>>>
>>> hash(f)
-4177197833195190597
>>>
>>> hash(foo)
1643374
>>>
>>> hash(foo())
-4177197833195190597
```

For what do I could use it?

Comment: What do you need it *for*? You usually only use it when building a [`__hash__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for a custom class. Also see the [`hash()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash). You are calculating the hash of the return value of the `foo()` function, and of the function itself.

Comment: Yep, I understand what does it do. So, I see, it is needed only for building `__hash__` method for a custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash):

> Return the hash value of the object (if it has one).
>   Hash values are integers. **They are used to** quickly compare dictionary
>   keys during a dictionary lookup. Numeric values that compare equal
>   have the same hash value (even if they are of different types, as is
>   the case for 1 and 1.0).

Comment: `Sets()` are dictionaries only, valueless dictionaries.